# How to merge double different models in magento?

Tags: php, magento, model, adminhtml

I want to merge two Model results in a variable to use it in the register. There's a way to do this?

```
  $commercial = Mage::getModel('thorleif/commercial')->load(1);
  $lcat = Mage::getModel('thorleif/mapping')->load(1);
  //$mergedresult = $commercial + $lcat
  Mage::register('commerciaux_data', $mergedresult);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve as an array for each results using **getData()** and merge them for your final result.
Please see the below code:

```
$commercial = Mage::getModel('thorleif/commercial')->load(1);
$lcat = Mage::getModel('thorleif/mapping')->load(1);
$mergedresult = array('commercial' => $commercial->getData(), 'mapping' => $lcat->getData());
//print_r($mergedresult);
Mage::register('commerciaux_data', $mergedresult);
```

Hope, this will help you.